# SSIS Package tries to pull from an old SQLStatementSource location

Tags: ssis

I'm slowly getting to grips with SSIS Packages and the like, but I have searched for an answer on this and I can't seem to resolve it!

I have a .dtsx which references a file name in the SQLStatementSource of the Execute SQL Task.  This file name has been altered slightly and the statement has been changed to reflect this.

When the package is in SSIS, it falls over and it is still showing the old file name in the SQLStatementSource despite it being changed to the new name.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking to alter the file name to allow the job to run?

Many Thanks
Jon

Comment: If you have changed package, you have to redeploy package with necessary permissions for job to be updated with new package. Find out from SQL agent properties, how SSIS packages are executed (i.e from File system or SSIS catalogue or SQL server)

Comment: Thanks Ven - It is executed by SSIS Catalogue.  I've not had to deploy anything previously.  Is there any good resource that you can point me to that would show me what I need to do?

Comment: Right click your project and press deploy and select the server you need to deploy too - Also look if your connectionstring has an FX on it. Then it has an expression most likely a variable. If it has a variable too it, then you need to change the name there as well

Comment: Thanks Thomas - There are no variables set so that should be OK.  I am right clicking within the project and I can't see an option for 'deploy'.  I'm in the 'Solution Explorer' within Visual Studio.  I'm assuming that's the right place?  Also, it says 'package deployment model' against the project name, so I'm not sure what that means (sorry - I didn't think this was going to be that involved when I said I would look in to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say follow microsoft documentation for method of automating SSIS packages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-2017

I guess you are running packages from SSIS catalogue with file system source

Changes made to SSIS package has to be redeployed.

> Import package from file system and over write on existing package.

[image]

> Validate and execute package to check changes are made

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

With your guidance I have now managed to resolve the issue by editing and re-deploying the project / package